# Creating/saving a higher quality image of the Eclipse window using SWT

Tags: java, eclipse, image, swt, screenshot

I'm taking screenshots of the currently active Eclipse shell using SWT. What I've got so far is generally working, however the images are being saved at 72 ppi, and I need something a bit better resolution than that. I suspect the loss of quality has to do with the copyArea method, as the API states that it must copy to a bitmap Image, but I can't find much more info about this.

How can I save an image with a higher resolution? I'm open to taking a totally different approach, if needed.

Apologies if I'm overlooking something obvious, I'm still a greenhorn at this.

```
Display display = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay(); 
Shell shell = display.getActiveShell(); 

// Take the screenshot  
GC gc = new GC(display);
Rectangle eclipseWindow = shell.getBounds();
Image screenshot = new Image(display, eclipseWindow);
gc.copyArea(screenshot, eclipseWindow.x, eclipseWindow.y);
gc.dispose();

// code that creates a file name and gets the file path omitted
String imgFilePath = "imgFilePath";

// save the screenshot as a png                     
ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader();
imgLoader.data = new ImageData[] { screenshot.getImageData() };
imgLoader.save(imgFilePath, SWT.IMAGE_PNG);

screenshot.dispose();
```

Comment: This is giving you all the available pixels. The SWT PNG save does not set the DPI in the saved file so you are just being shown a default value for the DPI.